# What is the proper approach to Bid'ah?

Tags: bidah

There are certain things which may be accepted as proper worship in a religion, but others may consider it Bid'ah.

For example, some people say that reciting "Ameen" after the Fatihah in prayer is a Bid'ah because it is a non-Arabic word. Or that celebrating the Prophet Muhammad's birthday is Bid'ah. Or even specific prayers and acts of over-worship.

**What is the proper approach when you believe something is Bid'ah but the people around you don't?** Is it permissible to do a prayer that you believe is Bid'ah just to please the people around you, if there is a weak hadith/fatwa supporting it? Is it considered haraam because you'd be strengthening a false belief?

I specifically mean the ones that are relatively harmless, not the ones that lead on to shirk.

Comment: Sounds a bit like this verse: Quran 5/104: http://quran.com/5/104.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is the proper approach when you believe something is Bid'ah but the people around you don't?

Look/research for proof that it is Bid'ah.

### Is it permissible to do a prayer that you believe is Bid'ah just to please the people around you, if there is a weak hadith/fatwa supporting it?

First of all if there is a week hadith or fatwa than you should seek to find a stronger one, for the weak in authenticity is a source of fitna.   And to make a form of worship just to please others is called "Al Raya'a الرياء" and this is very dangerous and reduces the real value of the worship for Allah down to nothing because you would be making it for people.  Furthermore if you know it is Bid'ah, don't do it for it leads to hell fire, and all worship that would bring us close to Allah has already been prescribed, and recommended by the Prophet and he has not left anything that would get us close to Allah except that he told us about it.

### Is it considered haraam because you'd be strengthening a false belief?

We are told that All Innovations in religion lead to the hell fire:

> وَشَرَّ الأُمُورِ مُحْدَثَاتُهَا وَكُلَّ مُحْدَثَةٍ بِدْعَةٌ وَكُلَّ
>   بِدْعَةٍ ضَلاَلَةٌ وَكُلَّ ضَلاَلَةٍ فِي النَّارِ
>
> he worst of things are those that are newly invented; every
>   newly-invented thing is an innovation and every innovation is going
>   astray, and every going astray is in the Fire

[Sunan Annasa'i](http://sunnah.com/nasai/19/23)

So isn't anything that we are told that leads to hellfire haram?